# NSTask and curl - Protocol https not supported or disabled in lib curl

Tags: objective-c, macos, curl, speech-recognition

I'm trying to send a `POST` request to use the speech to text API used by Google Chrome.
This is my code:

```
-(NSString*)sendAudioToServer {
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/curl";
task.arguments = @[@"-X",
                   @"POST",
                   @"--data-binary",
                   @" @'/Users/luca/vaTemp/record.flac' ",
                   @"--header",
                   @" 'Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=44100;' ",
                   @" 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=it-it&key=AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw'",
                   ];
NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:outputPipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
NSData *outputData = [[outputPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];}
```

The problem is I get this error: 
`"curl: (1) Protocol  'https not supported or disabled in lib curl"` 
If I run the command from Terminal everything works fine 
What am I doing wrong? 
I know I could use `NSMutableURLRequest`, but I wanted to understand what's the problem here. 
Thanks in advance, Luca